# Print multiple copies using XPSPrint API(XPSPrint.dll)

Tags: xps, aspose.words

I am using Aspose_words code given on the below link to print documents of type Aspose.Word.Document class using XPSPrint.dll by calling its StartJob and CopyJob methods. It is working fine for me as soon as i am printing a single copy of the document. But I am not able to print multiple copies of the document using the same Job. I am able to get those printer settings from PrintDialog window but i dont know how to apply those Printer Settings when printing via XPSPrintJob.dll.

I used this link:

https://github.com/asposewords/Aspose_Words_NET/blob/master/RenderingAndPrinting/PrintDocument/XpsPrint/CSharp/XpsPrintHelper.cs

Can you please suggest me how to resolve this problem.

Many thanks in advance.

Regards
Lucky

Answer (score 0):

The method StartJob() is taken from Microsoft Printing API, please see [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for reference. It does not take any argument like "NoOfCopies".

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I know this method does not take "NoOfCopies" as an argument. But is there any alternate way that i need to use this XPSPrint.dll only for printing document but I want to print multiple copies. Please suggest?